# How to use 'blogs.dir' as media upload instead of 'uploads' directory in WordPress multisite setup

Tags: permalinks, multisite, uploads, htaccess

**Setup 1 :**

The general subdomain/custom-domain based multisite setup for child network sites has its upload directory like this

`/home/example1.com/public_html/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2022/01/logo.png`

example1.com : the primary WordPress multisite network

example2.com : the child network site with site id 8 under example1.com

This file can be accessed from the child network site from the following URL

`https://www.example2.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2022/01/logo.png`

the general .htaccess file for subdomain based network site is following

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

**Setup 2 :**

In a subdomain/custom-domain based multisite setup I've got this upload directory, it uses blogs.dir instead of uploads directory

`/home/example1.com/public_html/wp-content/blogs.dir/8/files/2022/01/logo.png`

The child network site has following file path

`example2.com/files/2022/01/logo.png`

.htaccess of this setup is here

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*wp-content/plugins.*
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?files/(.*) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I've tried using this for new general installation where the intended upload path is blogs.dir but having this .htaccess does nothing.

There is no such difference in wp-config.php file that could affect this setup

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );

define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example1.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/'); // removed for hide my wp ghost plugin

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');

define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', '/404' );
```

Both setup was done by me and I don't remember any settings inside the dashboard that could change this. Permalinks checked; all possible settings inside the dashboard checked.

General multisite installation exposes site id in media path like this

`https://www.example2.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2022/01/logo.png`

The goal is not to expose site id in media path
`example2.com/files/2022/01/logo.png`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like `define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/blogs.dir' );` in `wp-config.php`?

Answer (score 3):

I can see a few possibilities:

1. Custom Uploads directory (`blogs.dir`) is not properly setup in `wp-config.php`. While `wp-content/uploads` is by default taken by WordPress, `wp-content/blogs.dir` must be setup somewhere. I don't see it in your provided code anywhere.
2. A custom directory like `blogs.dir` can be symbolically linked to `wp-content/uploads`. Check if any of your previous setup has such symbolic links in the filesystem. You may connect to the server (SSH) and run the shell command like `ls -alh` to check symlinks.
3. `.htaccess` file not properly routing requests for the files located in the `blogs.dir` directory. Double-check that the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled in your Apache server and that the `.htaccess` file has the correct permissions to be read by the server.

Additionally, you may want to check your server's error logs for any related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may help -

First, locate the wp-config.php file in your WordPress installation directory.

Then, add the following code to the wp-config.php file, replacing 'your-site-id' with the ID of the site you want to use the 'blogs.dir' directory for:

```
define( 'UPLOADBLOGSDIR', 'wp-content/blogs.dir/your-site-id/files' ); add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'wpse_upload_dir' ); function wpse_upload_dir( $param ) { $param['path'] = ABSPATH . UPLOADBLOGSDIR; $param['url'] = get_home_url() . '/' . UPLOADBLOGSDIR; $param['subdir'] = ''; return $param;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `blogs.dir` is only used during wordpress 3.0-3.4.2 .  https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/multisite/administration/#uploaded-file-path